# New to opencv's advaced stuff....can someone give me a simple example of how to use cvAlloc?

Tags: c, opencv

I looked on google and there were no real examples of how to use it simply...for reference im good enough at opencv to understand everything thats going on here http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut8.html . for example if Im using a bunch of cvCreateImages in a program and using them to make masks like in the afformentioned link which eats alot of ram, where in that program can i stick a cvAlloc to make the program manage ram better and where afterwards do i put the cvFree....you dont have to do the whole thing for me just show me one place i could put a cvAlloc to manage the memory in that program better..or give me another example to help me understand how to use it....and pls pls dont say switch to c++ =)....i do embedded.

Comment: Curious if the links were helpful?  As I looked around, I was very disappointed at how little there is out there on this API.   Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a ***[pretty good link here](http://pebibyte.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/simple-face-recognition-using-opencv/)***:

Here are the relevant parts:

```
IplImage ** Array = 0; 

int nItems = 42;

Array = (IplImage **)cvAlloc( nItems*sizeof(IplImage *) );
```

Sorry, this code example did NOT include where he would have put cvFree.  (Hope this helps)

[EDIT]
***[This](http://enddl22.net/wordpress/?cat=633&paged=4)*** has a little about OpenCV memory management, maybe it will help.

Comment: @user2862490 Remember to accept correct answers to questions

Comment: @ryyker thanks i will check into that